# AMPL/MathProg constraints for the "loose cash" puzzle

Tags: ampl, mathprog

I try to formulate [H.E. Dudeney's](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Dudeney) "loose cash" problem in AMPL/MathProg code.

**Challenge** the "loose cash" problem:

> What is the largest sum of money-all in current coins and no silver
>   dollars-that I could have in my pocket without being able to give
>   change for a dollar, half dollar, quarter, dime, or nickel?

**Problem** my approach is incomplete:

```
set Coins;
param value{t in Coins};
var number{t in Coins}, integer, >=0;
subject to ...
maximize money_value: sum{t in Coins} number[t] * value[t];

data;    
param:  Coins:    value :=
        penny     1
        nickel    5
        dime      10
        quarter   25
        half      50;
end;
```

**Question:** How do I formulate the constraints section `...` properly?